# Simulate hyperlink click in jQuery to launch a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display a password-reset form when certain flag is triggered. I have the following basic code working to prompt the user to change their password, if there is no password_changed_flag.  Depending on the response, the user receives a message back saying 'Yes' or 'No'.  Here is the code:

```
<?php if(!$password_changed_flag){
        <script type="text/javascript">     
        $('#ajaxShield').show();        
        var pw = <?php echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('password')) ?>;
        $.prompt("Your auto-assigned password must be changed.", pw,
        function(){
            $.msg("Yes.",{header:'Yes', live:10000});
            $('#ajaxShield').hide();
        },
        function(){
            $.msg("No.",{header:'No', live:10000});
            $('#ajaxShield').hide();
        });                 
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

My only problem is that instead of using `$.prompt` and `$.msg`, what I really need to be doing is to display a form.  This is the code the I have elsewhere which launches the form:

```
<a href="#ChangePW" return false; class="login-window" >Change Password</a>
```

I guess my problem is that I can view the form with the click of a hyperlink, but instead of viewing the form using a hyperlink, I need to be able to view the form when there is no password_changed_flag, as in the above code.  So, it looks like I need to simulate the lower code block inside the upper code bock, somehow.

How can I simulate what happens in response to the hyperlink, without relying on a hyperlink?

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: What's that `return false;` statement doing in the middle of the `a` tag? That's not right.

Comment: It's there because I'm a n00b.  Since you are telling me it doesn't belong there, I will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the click with Jquery

```
$('#triggerClick').trigger('click');

<a href="#ChangePW" class="login-window" id='triggerClick'>Change Password</a>
```

If your using fancybox which your markup suggests you can also use:

```
$("#triggerClick").fancybox().trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate to the anchor name `#ChangePW`, which is what the link seems to do, you can do it in JavaScript like this:

```
self.location.hash = "ChangePW";
```

Comment: Yes, I want to navigate to the anchor `#ChangePW`, but I also need to incorporate the `class="login-window"`